# Select syntax as a subquery to insert into

Tags: sql, syntax-error

Here's what I'm trying to do in SQL Query Analyzer.

```
Insert into db_name1.dbo.tb_name1 (select * from db_name2.dbo.tb_name2)
```

but I keep getting this error message

```
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I wonder what went wrong. Does subquery isn't work in SQL server 2000?
What is the right syntax for this one? I would like to transfer all the values from a tables column of a database to another table of another database without creating any duplicate of its element but merely overwrites the current values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query as you think it should be interpeted:

```
Insert into db_name1.dbo.tb_name1
    (select * from db_name2.dbo.tb_name2)
```

This is the query as the compiler sees it:

```
Insert into db_name1.dbo.tb_name1(select * from db_name2.dbo.tb_name2)
```

That is, the open parenthese after the table name means "the list of columns is starting here".  But you don't have a list of columns.  And `select` is not a valid column name.  Hence the error.

This is easily fixed by removing the parentheses:

```
Insert into db_name1.dbo.tb_name1
    select * from db_name2.dbo.tb_name2
```

However, it is more correct to include the column names being inserted:

```
Insert into db_name1.dbo.tb_name1(col1 . . .)
    select * from db_name2.dbo.tb_name2;
```

It is a good idea to always include column names in insert statements.  If you had done this, you wouldn't have had to ask this question.

Comment: The advice to always include column names extends to the subquery (select statement) also. This handles changes to schema (particularly adding more columns) over time.

Comment: @Gordon, yes I did include the column names everytime I run insert into in sql server. Its just that this time the table has too many attributes [more than 30 columns I reckon so] and its been so tiring to include all those 30+ columns so I did that script. To minimize my time on scripting. but it seems I have no other option.

Comment: @Archangel08 . . . You do have an option.  Just drop the parentheses around the subquery.